# Sencha Touch 2; pass variable between two functions

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2

I have a list of colleague (List.js)
Tapping a list items dispays details of the colleague (Detail.js). One of the fields is {skype}. Skype address is retrieved from the store and displayed well.

In the detail screen I have a button 'call me'. The purpose is to start a skype call with the colleague.

I have added a function

```
onOpenSkypeTap: function () {
    open('skype:{skype}?call');
}
```

The problem is: skype start a call with {skype}, and not the skype name of the colleague.
I think I need to solve it in the controler file, but my attempt is not succesfull:
part of the controler file:

```
oncolleagueItemTap: function(list, idx, el, record) {
    this.getcolleagueContainer().push(this.colleague);
    this.colleague.setRecord(record);
    var skypename = record.get ('skype')
    console.log(skypename);     
},

onOpenSkype: function () {
    console.log(skypename);
    open('skype:skypename?call');
}
```

Error message: Uncaught ReferenceError: skypename is not defined

Probably because var skypename is only defined for the function oncolleagueItemTap

Is it possible to pass this variable to the function onOpenSKype?
Or is there another solution?

Comment: How are you adding the listener to the call button?

Comment: listeners: [{
            delegate: "#openSkype",
            event: "tap",
            fn: "onOpenSkypeTap"
        }]

Answer (score 0):

You can set `skypename` as one of the config properties in details page and provide this page an id. On tap of button you can do this

```
var name = Ext.getCmp("colleguePageId").config.skypename
```

OR

```
var name = Ext.getCmp("colleguePageId").getRecord().get('skype')
```

and the you can use it wherever you want

```
open('skype:'+name+'?call');
```

Comment: Thnx this works. I have added the second suggestion .get('skype'). BUT I get a warning when returning to the list and slecting an item:

Comment: [WARN] [Ext.Component#constructor] Registering a component with a id ('ColleagueDetail') which has already been used. Please ensure the existing component has been destroyed (Ext.Component#destroy()

I added 
Ext.getCmp('ColleagueDetail').destroy();
To oncolleagueItemTap

But then no content is shown when selecting an item from the list.
Can I make the destroy more specific?

Comment: I saw some post suggesting to change id into itemId to fix the Warning. I changed this for the details page. This resulted in an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getRecord' of undefined .